# Axios get request failed

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have two functions in my vue.js component. Both should return the same values. The first function works fine. The second one does not work at all and returns Error: Request failed with status code 500. The only difference between the functions is the passing of parameters. I should be able to pass the parameters like the second function. But for some reason it doesn't work.

```
    test: function() {
        axios.get("https://localhost:44390/api/Users/1").then(result => this.user = result.data);
    },
    test2: function() {
        axios.get("https://localhost:44390/api/Users", {
            params: {
                id: 1
            }
        }).then(result => this.user = result.data);
    }
```

Comment: open devtools and check the url?

Comment: how do i check the url?

Comment: open Network tab in devtools, you can inspect there every request you make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test2 is calling this address: https://localhost:44390/api/Users?id=1

So  you call 2 different endpoints